# How to install nodeos on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nodeos, development, ubuntu

The prebuilt binaries are for Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 18.04
My laptop has Ubuntu 20.04 and I want to install nodeos for development and testing. I downloaded the eosio_2.0.7-1-ubuntu-18.04_amd64.deb file from the releases page, https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases

But it won't install using

```
sudo apt install ./eosio_2.0.7-1-ubuntu-18.04_amd64.deb
```

This is the error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 eosio : Depends: libicu60 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually install the missing package with these commands:

```
wget http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb 
sudo dpkg -i ./libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb
```

Then you can install EOSIO prebuilt binaries for Ubuntu 18.04 from the releases page on a new Ubuntu version 20.04

This solution was found in a [github issue](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/9006#issuecomment-639374006)

Answer (score 0):

You need to build eos by yourself, or can use my personal package archive (for development purpose only).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:conr2d/eosio
sudo apt install eosio
```

It wasn't built on cloned github repository, so its version will be shown 'unknown', but is 'v2.0.7'. (Originally the version of nodeos will be grabbed from github tags)

The version of clang isn't managed, so generated state by these prebuilt binaries can be incompatible in the future releases. For the compatibility of state db, the version of boost, the version of the compiler, build type (release or debug), operating system and architecture should be kept same.

Comment: Thanks, but I found another suggestion burried in the git issues of the project, will write another answer to this question, based on it